# How to convert landmark data from csv file into array to procrustes superimposition using geomorph package?

Tags: r, mathematical-morphology, morphological-analysis, procrustes

I have three separate csv files with landmark coordinates for separate species. I would like to perform a procrustes superimposition on the landmarks, but I first need to combine the landmarks into one object which I am trying to do with the combine.subsets function. However, for this function to work, my data must be formatted as an array.

I tried using the function arrayspecs to format my data, but got an error message "Error in dimnames(specimens) <- `*vtmp*` :
length of 'dimnames' [3] not equal to array extent"

I then successfully used the array function, however, when I tried to use the combine.subsets function, I got the error message "Error in combine.subsets(a.tex, c.ero, c.cal, gpa = TRUE, CS.sets = NULL,  :

Coordinates must be a  [p x k x n] array.

```
                                       Use arrayspecs first"
```

This is my data and the code I've been working with:
A_ardys

| x.1 | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.897 | 10.414 |
| 2 | 8.641 | 10.543 |
| 3 | 9.353 | 10.635 |
| 4 | 9.560 | 10.141 |
| 5 | 9.560 | 9.601 |
| 6 | 8.560 | 9.761 |

C_erodyle

| x.1 | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.545 | 9.116 |
| 2 | 8.608 | 9.201 |
| 3 | 9.651 | 9.245 |
| 4 | 10.091 | 8.224 |
| 5 | 9.915 | 7.257 |
| 6 | 8.641 | 7.927 |

C_californica

| x.1 | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.545 | 9.116 |
| 2 | 8.608 | 9.201 |
| 3 | 9.651 | 9.245 |
| 4 | 10.091 | 8.224 |
| 5 | 9.915 | 7.257 |
| 6 | 8.641 | 7.927 |

Code:

```
texana <- read.csv("A_texana.csv", row.names = 1) 
erodyle <- read.csv("C_erodyle.csv", row.names = 1) 
californica <- read.csv("C_californica.csv", row.names = 1)

windows()
plot(texana$X,texana$Y, col = "red", xlim = c(4,10), ylim = c(0,12)) 
points(erodyle$X,erodyle$Y, col = "blue") 
points(californicus$X,californicus$Y, col = "green")

library(geomorph)
library(reshape2) 
library(ggfortify) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 

################################
#  procrustes superimposition  # 
################################

# Combine landmarks
?two.d.array 
?arrayspecs 
?array
#arrayspecs attempt 
a.tex <- arrayspecs(texana, 6, 2) 
c.ero <- arrayspecs(erodyle, 6, 2)
c.cal <- arrayspecs(californica, 6, 2)
# Create an array with dimensions (matrix, landmarks, ndimensions)
a.t <- array(data = texana, dim = length(texana), dimnames = NULL) 
c.e <- array(data = erodyle, dim = length(erodyle), dimnames = NULL)
c.c <- array(data = californica, dim = length(californica), dimnames = NULL) 

landmarks <- combine.subsets(
  a.tex, c.ero, c.cal,
  gpa = TRUE,
  CS.sets = NULL,
  norm.CS = FALSE,
  weights = NULL
)

# Perform Procrustes superimposition
proc <- gpagen(landmarks, PrinAxes = FALSE, scaling = FALSE)
```